# Unix command for finding and displaying a file

Tags: unix, command, pipe, io-redirection

Let's say a directory contains one file with "testing" in its name. I want to find this file and display its contents using a single UNIX command. Here's what I have tried:

`ls | grep 'testing' | less`

This retrieves the name of a file, but it doesn't seem to pipe the name to `less` in the way I expected. How should I revise the command?

Comment: And all the files are in the same directory?

Comment: then cat is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat *testing*` (provided your working directory is the same as where the file is located)

or

`cat ~/Desktop/*testing*` (where ~/Desktop/ is the directory path)

Answer (score 2):

The `find` utility is best suited to find files. It also offers good flexibility to filter the result. Then you could use the `xargs` utility to use the output of `file` as arguments for the output command you want to combine:

```
find . -name somefile | xargs cat
```

Of course you can also use the `more` or `less` pager to control the output instead of `cat`...

Comment: or simply `find -name somefile -exec less {} \;` or `find -name somefile -exec cat {} \; | less` - depending on his needs.